# Can't connect my ruby on rails app running on MySQL to heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cleardb

I am trying to deploy a rails app to Heroku for the first time.
I am trying to connect my ruby on rails app which has a MySQL database. I am not sure if I have missed out on some steps but whenever I try to access heroku's provided url, I get the message "We're sorry, but something went wrong." and it asks to check the logs.

When I check Heroku logs, what I can make out of it is I see something like

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Access denied for user 'adffdadf2341'@'ip-10-187-29-34.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)):
```

I have created a ClearDB add on
and I've set the following

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:     mysql2://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true
I've set this to DATABASE_URL as well.
```

I'm not sure if all my config files or database.yml are as it should be.
Also things to note are I am using gems like Paperclip and Devise.To make sure my Paperclip works properly I am using AWS.

My github repo is on the following
https://github.com/esjayrockz/Savour

Can you please check this and say if I'm missed out on anything.

Comment: That DB URL you mentioned here `mysql2://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/...` is the actual URL or it is just for representation purpose only, and your actual URL is different from what you have posted here?

Comment: That is the actual URL. I get this when I do
`$ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`
`CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:     mysql2://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true`

Comment: Okay but in their [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#provisioning-the-add-on) , I can see that they have mentioned the same URL. I don't think this should be the only URL for all of their users. Your URL should be different.

Comment: How do I know what my URL should be ? As per their article they have written that copy the value of CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL. And to know this value do `$ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`.
When I do that, I get this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Password is wrong for the user so cannot connect to the MySQL DB. Try these commands in your console:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And when prompted, give the password as 'admin'

If this is possible, then you should be good to go.

Comment: 'admin' is not my root password. How will this work ? I am not sure if I understand your solution.

Comment: On console type :  'mysql -u root -p'  then hit enter, and type password password. Are you able to login?

Comment: No this is not working. How will any other string apart from my root password work when I login as root ?

Comment: I just want to check that your password is correct or not
When you enter  'mysql -u root -p' then enter and type your root password, are you able to login?

Comment: Yes I am able to login when I enter my root password.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku work with postgres database only so remove mysql from gemfile and add below line:

```
gem 'pg'
```

Comment: okay.. you can add tickets on heroku if your addon is not working with app properly.